# Spring Data Mongodb(java): it is possible to use @Dbref with abstract interface?

Tags: java, mongodb

Supposing i have my classes defined like this:

```
public interface O {
}

public class A implements O {
}

public class P implements O {
}
```

it is possible to use @Dbref with the interface `O`?

```
public class C{
  @Dbref O reference 
}
```

I want realise a class C that can contain a pointer to instances of A or P. O is instanced correctly or not? How could does it in java?

```
class C{
Document reference;
}
```

does it work? if yes, how to convert Document object in a instance of A or P?

Comment: Maybe i find a way using mongo converters

Comment: From what I've learned about mongodb is that the best approach would be to store the id of the other object (`A` or `P`) and use a converter or business logic to read the according document.